# AJAX for updating Flask template after data goes from link action or form to mongodb collection

Tags: python, ajax, mongodb, flask

I have a project wherein mongodb records are rendered in a browser via Flask. I also have some interactions in the browser that would allow users to update records in the database. So, for instance, click a "Vote for me" link and you can increment a "vote" on the record. That record's vote tally then would appear next to the "Vote for me link".

Currently, however, my vote route looks like this, and I have to reload the page to update the vote tally in the browser:

```
@app.route('/vote_up/<this_record>')
def vote_up(this_record):

    vandalisms.update({'_id':bson.objectid.ObjectId(this_record)}, 
                  {"$inc" : { "votes": 1 }}, upsert=True)

    return redirect("/")
```

I've had a look at the flask documentation for jquery and flask here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/ and understand what's going on there, but don't see how to extend that to the case where I want to update the mongodb collection first and then just reload a div or span specifying the new vote rendered from the updated record, e.g.

```
    <span id='vote_tally'> {{ item.votes }} </span>
```

What would I have to be doing to include that trip to the db and back to the browser without having to reload the entire page again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is hook something like this to the click event:

```
$('#vote_tally').load('/vote_up/3452/');
```

Where the "ajax" url returns the HTML I want to modify.

```
@app.route('/vote_up/<this_record>')
def vote_up(this_record):
    if already_voted_for(this_record):
        return """<script type="text/javascript">
                       alert('You can only vote once');
            </script>{0}""".format(count_votes_for(this_record))

    vandalisms.update({'_id':bson.objectid.ObjectId(this_record)}, 
              {"$inc" : { "votes": 1 }}, upsert=True)

    return count_votes_for(this_record)
```

Comment: I would probably use `POST` for this endpoint, but +1 for an excellent example on all other points!

Comment: @SeanVieira: using `jQuery.load` with POST is simple enough, just pass a dictionary of key/values as a second parameter and it will make a POST call instead of a GET. Since the original example has no mention to the use of the POST method, I've omitted it for the sake of simplicity, it can help to prevent cache by an aggressive proxy between the client and server and is idiomatically correct indeed since he is changing a record.

Comment: @Paulo cool thanks. though I am still a little cloudy on what the count_votes_for(this_record) should be, would that just be a query to .find() that record in the database after it's been updated?

Comment: @droquo: the function name reflects my guess that you want to display the total number of upvotes at `#vote_tally`, but I thing you can adapt the sample to your needs. Basically `count_votes_for(some_record)` should return anything you want to show at `#vote_tally` after computing the vote, perhaps I should name it `get_vote_tally_content_for(this_record)` to be clear.